# Xamarin.iOS Runtime.cs not found after try to put AdMob

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, mobile

I try to put some banner from AdMob on my xamarin iOS project. I fallow this steps:

[Xamarin Forms with Google Admob tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-lkUhWji3A)

1. I changed in my App.xaml.cs file `MainPage = new MainPage();` to `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());`
2. I create new folder `Controls` on my base project and there I create new class `AdMobControl.cs`with his code:

using System;

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

using static WeatherLocationInfo.Controls.AdMobControl;

namespace WeatherLocationInfo.Controls
{

public class AdMobControl : View
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty AdUnitIdProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                   nameof(AdUnitId),
                   typeof(string),
                   typeof(AdMobControl),
                   string.Empty);

    public string AdUnitId
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(AdUnitIdProperty);
        set => SetValue(AdUnitIdProperty, value);
    }
}
}
```

3. I create new file on my base project and name it `AppConstants.cs` with this code:

   using System;

   ```
    using Xamarin.Forms;

    namespace WeatherLocationInfo
    {

    public class AppConstants
    {
        public static string AppId
        {
            get
            {
                switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
                {
                    case Device.Android:
                        return "";
                    default:
                        return "";
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// These Ids are test Ids from https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The banner identifier.</value>
        public static string BannerId
        {

            get
            {
                switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
                {
                    case Device.iOS:
                        return "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
                    default:
                        return "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// These Ids are test Ids from https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The Interstitial Ad identifier.</value>
        public static string InterstitialAdId
        {
            get
            {
                switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
                {
                    case Device.Android:
                        return "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
                    default:
                        return "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
                }
            }
        }

        public static bool ShowAds
        {
            get
            {
                _adCounter++;
                if (_adCounter % 5 == 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }

        private static int _adCounter;

    }
   ```

   }
4. In my `MainPage.xaml.cs` I added under `InitializeComponent();` this code:

   AdMobControl admobControl = new AdMobControl()

   ```
        {

            AdUnitId = AppConstants.BannerId
        };
        Label adLabel = new Label() { Text = "Ads will be displayed here!" };
   ```

   Content = new StackLayout()
   {
   Children = {adLabel, admobControl}
   };

   ```
            this.Title = "Admob Page";
   ```
5. I add in my iOS project new package from Nuget -> `Xamarin.Google.iOS.MobileAds`
6. In my `AppDelegate.cs` I add this code -> `Google.MobileAds.MobileAds.Configure(AppConstants.AppId);`

After that I try to run the project in the debug mode but I receive this error:

```
Runtime.cs file not found
```

[image: Runtime.cs file not found]

Is there a way to fix this problem ?

P.S I'm sorry that part of the code is not in apostrophes but when I copy the code and the editor himself does not put it in an apostrophe

Answer (score 2):

did you update your info.plist file?

```
    <key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
    <string>YOUR APP ID</string>
    <key>GADIsAdManagerApp</key>
    <true/>
```